# Basic header for Spring Boot - Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HttpHeaders: (?)

Tags: angular

I have upgraded the code from Angular 2 to Angular 6. The parameters set in the http headers are the `content-type` and `authorization`. The `authorization` contains `btoa` of user name and password.

I could not find what is the error in setting up the parameters for httpheaders.

This is for authorization from Spring boot. The code for `appmodule` and the `service` are attached.

> app module

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MenuComponent } from './components/menu/menu.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from './angular-material.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MenuComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AngularMaterialModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    providers: [HttpHeaders],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> Login Service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {  HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Token } from '../models/Token';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient,private header: HttpHeaders) { }

    sendCredential(username: string, password: string) {
        let url = 'http://localhost:8080/token';
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + btoa(username+":"+password)
        });
        return this.http.get<Token>(url, { headers });
    }

    checkSession() {
        let url = 'http://localhost:8080/checkSession';
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'x-auth-token' : localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken')
        });
        return this.http.get(url, { headers });
     }

    logout() {}
}
```

Comment: You don't have to pass the httpHeaders as a dependency in constructor

Answer (score 1):

In login service

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.

It got resolved by specifying the statement provide: HttpHeaders in app module.

The statement is

providers: [{provide: HttpHeaders}]